# Force a method to be true without executing it

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

On my HTML I have something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mymethod()">
```

I want to display this in my component.spec.ts without execute this method.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
 spy(component.mymethod()).toBe(true);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Most likely you don't want to use a method in your *ngIf statement.

Comment: Although you didnt respond to my question, you are right :)

Comment: That was my response to your question...

Comment: that´s not an answer to my question? I´m asking whats the best way to go to france, walking, and your answer is: Why you don t go by plain?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your method is public, you can say:

```
spyOn(component, 'mymethod').and.returnValue(true);
```

Although this works, it raises questions on why you need to mock the logic of the component that you want to test.